# How to catch platform-native errors in Flutter and prevent crashing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-ios, flutter-video-player

I'm using the Video Player package in Flutter.

My problem:
When the videoPlayerController is initialized with no/invalid data on iOS, the app silently crashes without any error message and doesn't leave any opportunity to react to the error by showing an error widget etc.

Here is my current approach to catch an error message out of this, but I think in case there IS an error/exception available, it would be written into the terminal anyway. Right now the error just kills the app silently with no chance to react to it...

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

```
    //other code
..
..
controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("my_non_valid_asset"); 

controller?.initialize().catchError((onError) => throw Exception(
          "catchError: VideoPlayerController couldn't get initialized. Maybe error with video data?"))
      .onError((error, stackTrace) =>
          throw Exception("onError: VideoPlayerController couldn't get initialized. Maybe error with video data?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Platform-specific errors are usually handled with the [`PlatformException`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PlatformException-class.html) class. But it totally depends on the author, the author is free to use any custom exception class by extending `Exception` class provided by Flutter framework.

Comment: Hi Usama, thanks for your answer. But if a PlatformException is bubbling up, it should arrive in the Terminal, or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: If errors are not flutter specific, flutter can not catch the errors until those are not handled properly.

Comment: The author of the package is handling errors with `PlatformException` here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/19f566ba87aaffd06e8869c4cd481eab99f0a11d/packages/video_player/video_player/lib/video_player.dart#L412

Comment: Thank you again. But if the author is handling the error and the app still crashes silently it doesn't help me, or which option to react am I overseeing here?

Comment: It looks like there is some other issue. Have you gone through the package documentation properly?

Comment: Yes, I think so. There is not that much API documentation though. It leaves out important stuff, like allocated video data won't be freed by calling controller.dispose() unless you also set the controller = null. Just as a plain example of how rudimentary the docu is. 

I am only searching for a way to react to invalid video data without crashing the app on iOS. 
On Android on the other hand, you get a proper exception which you can handle and the app doesn't crash.